# How to display Category and Sub-Category on Menu in ASP.NET MVC/C#/LINQ/SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to populate category and subcategory as a menu and then want to display product information by clicking on subcategory menu.

I have a model class of category, subcategory, products like this,

```
 public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
           Products = new HashSet<Product>();
           SubCategories = new HashSet<SubCategory>();
        }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }



        public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

public class SubCategory
    {
        public SubCategory()
        {
            Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }

public class Product
    {

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }



        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    }
```

I have subcategory item in database like this.

```
|CategoryName    |SubCategyName
Computer           HP
Computer          Lenovo 
Mobile            Samsung
Mobile            Apple
```

And Menu View but which is not correct:

```
@model IEnumerable<mTest.Models.SubCategory>



<div>
    <ul>
            @foreach (var category in Model)
            {
                <li class="active has-sub"><a href="#"><span>@category.Category.CategoryName</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var subcategory in Model)
                        {
                            <li class="has-sub"><a href="/Products/show?subcategory=@category.SubCategoryName"><span>@subcategory.SubCategoryName</span></a></li>

                        }
                    </ul>

                </li>
            }
      </ul>
</div>
```

Which results:

```
|Computer=>HP
         =>Lenovo
|Computer=>HP
         =>Lenovo

|Mobile  =>Samsung
         =>Apple
|Mobile  =>Samsung
         =>Apple
```

But I want this.

```
|Computer=>HP
         =>Lenovo

|Mobile  =>Samsung
         =>Apple
```

How to get this?

Comment: does your db hold computer and mobile each twice ?

Comment: Can you show us the code to get the list from your db ?

Comment: @MihaiTibrea which is above view and controller code is just simple list action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your models and View you can write like this:

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct())
{
    <li class="active has-sub">
        <a href="#"><span>@category.CategoryName</span></a>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var subcategory in Model.Where(x => category.Id == x.CategoryId))
            {
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="/Products/show?subcategory=@category.SubCategoryName"><span>@subcategory.SubCategoryName</span></a></li>

            }
        </ul>

    </li>
}
```

But i recommend you to  make your `ViewModel` `IEnumerable<mTest.Models.Category>` Type, not `IEnumerable<mTest.Models.SubCategory>`. It will be just cleanier.

Like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<mTest.Models.Category>

<div>
    <ul>
            @foreach (var category in Model)
            {
                <li class="active has-sub"><a href="#"><span>@category.CategoryName</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var subcategory in category.SubCategories)
                        {
                            <li class="has-sub"><a href="/Products/show?subcategory=@subcategory.SubCategoryName"><span>@subcategory.SubCategoryName</span></a></li>

                        }
                    </ul>

                </li>
            }
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am unable to get the separate Subcategories according to selected category. Your code also display the all subcategories for each category. This code  foreach (var subcategory in Model.Where(x => category.Id == x.CategoryId)) displays the all the subcategory.

Comment: But can you say, how it renders now? `Where` condition should get categories what have `CategoryId` same as chousen category, as you see.

Comment: One thing how can you populate subcategory item from category using IEnumerable<mTest.Models.Category>. I didn't get that too.

Comment: I updated the answer. You should only fill your model right on your controller and then it's simple as you see.

Comment: Thanks I got the exact view but some categoryies where subcategory are same I am getting the Sequence contains more than one element error.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your model to use a list of Categories.

```
@model IEnumerable<mTest.Models.Category>
    ...
    @foreach (var category in Model)
    {
        ...                
        @foreach (var subcategory in category.SubCategories)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Assuming each Category's SubCategories list is populated.

Comment: Yes. But my answer was in English.

Comment: If you try to test it - you will get it. Just don't post something that you don't try.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but it's psuedocode. So no, it will not run.

Comment: it's still have logical mistakes